# How to flag commited files in svn to be excluded from the export?

Tags: svn, export, svnignore, svn-export

We have the problem that we have the open project files in our SVN like `*.fla` and `*.psd`. They are under Apache Subversion (i.e. in SVN repository) but we don't want them to be exported. We want a clean export without our open project files.

Is there a way to flag them somehow to prevent them from being exported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell Subversion to exclude certain files from an `export` because it operates under the (reasonable) assumption that all files in the repository are relevant to the building and usage of the project.

If you don’t want files to show up when a user does an `export`, then they shouldn’t be in the repository in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing as export filter to my knowledge, but you can make a postexport script to remove files you dont want. Here is a ruby example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'find'

Find.find(".") do |path| 
  if FileTest.file?(path) && path.match(/\.tmp$/i)
    puts 'removing %s' % path
    FileUtils.remove_file(path)
  end
end
```